# Android App - Overflow screensize using Gridlayout

Tags: android, xml

I am relatively new to Android XML layout. I am using the Gridlayout to make an android app. But some widgets overflow the width of the screen size when I use fill_parent in the Gravity setting. Please see image below.[image]

The XML file is written as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/amount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="Split into"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

................

My question is why do some widgets overflow the screen size of the layout? And how may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't explicitly set the width, and set `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"`. e.g.:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0" />
```

Comment: I don't know why it works, but it does work like magic. Thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) for a description of what `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` does. If you're happy with the solution, please also accept the answer.